# code disappears when highlighting in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, highlight

I have a simple problem in my eclipse which I could not figure out how to fix it.
When I highlight any piece of code (in C++, or in Fortran, probably in any other language) the code disappears. I just can't see the code until I unhighlight it.

Anyone has any clue what the source of problem could be.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because your color scheme has a problem, highlighting the same font color and background color. You can try to reset the font color scheme.

Comment: How can I do that? I went through preference/General/colors and fonts and play with different options. but I could not get it fixed.

Comment: Window/Preferences/General/Appearance/Colors and Fonts/ ant press `Restore Defaults` and `Apply`